# Flutter geolocation show PermissionDefinitionsNotFoundException after add ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation, android-manifest

I try to use [Flutter Geolocator Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator).

I add these permission to `my_project/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and `my_project/android/app/src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

After that, I write code to get position like this code.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  late Position position;

  void _getUserPosition() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    setState(() {
      position = position;
    });

    print(position.toString());
  }
```

when I run it show this error.

```
Exception has occurred.
PermissionDefinitionsNotFoundException (No location permissions are defined in the manifest. Make sure at least ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION are defined in the manifest.)
```

at line `Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(`

How to fix it?